# The deprecation template must contain the "%service_id%" placeholder

Tags: symfony

i'm new to symfony 4, i tried to install admin panel by `composer require admin` command, but it sounds error :

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In Definition.php line 770:
!!
!!    The deprecation template must contain the "%service_id%" placeholder.
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: try to clear the cache `php bin/console cache:clear` or delete the content of cache manually and try again and tell us the result

Comment: I have the same problem after composer update did following updates:   - Updating easycorp/easyadmin-bundle (v3.1.10 => v3.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (3.0.1 => 3.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/orm-pack (v2.0.0 => v2.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating phpstan/phpstan (0.12.63 => 0.12.64): Loading from cache

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/4077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a new commit that seems to fix this issue was merged today in the repo EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle.
Until they release next version, you could do

```
symfony composer req admin:3.0.x-dev
```